# GAE: Using properties for keys() in ModelChoiceProperty boxes

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-forms, key, referenceproperty

I have a model `User` which appears as a `ReferenceProperty` in another model, `Group`.

When I create a form for `Group`, using `Meta`, the form's values contain lots of generated strings. I'd like to stop this, and use the `username` field of `User` instead.

I already define a `key_name`. However, `str(user.key())` still gives a generated string. I could override `key()`, but that would be bad. Any thoughts? I want the Group form to use `username`s for the ModelChoiceProperty values, and the form to still validate and save. Currently the form prints the string value of `key()`, according to the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having thought about this a little bit harder, I think the correct answer is "don't do that". The `Entity`s will still have keys, and those keys will correspond to a generated string. The form would have to be hacked to make it work too, so this looks like a ton of hassle to essentially make the code a tiny bit prettier looking.

Answer (score 0):

The `key()` in a `db.model` is an object that contains a bunch of different information, including the kind of object, its `name` and an `id`.

So I'm thinking that `key().name()` would return what you want?

In the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html#Key_name), it describes all of this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was very unclear in my description. Hopefully its clearer now. Thanks for the answer :)